# Returning a tuple from a function using uniform initialization syntax

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, tuples

The following code compiles with clang (libc++) and fails with gcc (libstdc++). Why does gcc (libstdc++) complains about an initializer list? I thought the return argument was using uniform initialization syntax.

```
std::tuple<double,double> dummy() {
  return {2.0, 3.0};
}

int main() {   
  std::tuple<double,double> a = dummy();   
  return 0;
}
```

> Error: line 22: converting to ‘std::tuple’ from initializer \
>   list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(_U1&\
>   &, _U2&&) [with _U1 = double; _U2 = double;  = void; _T\
>   1 = double; _T2 = double]’

**Note:** GCC (libstdc++) (and clang (libc++)) accept

```
std::tuple<double,double> dummy {1.0, 2.0};
```

Isn't it the same case?

**Update:** this is a libc++ extension, see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15299 and also answer by Howard Hinnant below.

Comment: Just commenting on your last question: No, it's not the same case. A return statement is a "copy initialization" context whereas your last example is actually a "direct initialization". The difference between both is that for copy initialization only non-explicit constructors are considered.

Comment: Also Visual Studio 14 Update 3 accepts it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unlike for `pair<>`, implicit construction of a `tuple<>` is not possible unfortunately. You have to use `make_tuple()`:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<double,double> dummy()
{
    return std::make_tuple(2.0, 3.0); // OK
}

int main() 
{   
    std::tuple<double,double> a = dummy();   
    return 0;
}
```

[`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) has a variadic constructor, but it is marked as `explicit`. Thus, it cannot be used in this situation, where a temporary must be implicitly constructible. Per Paragraph 20.4.2 of the C++11 Standard:

```
namespace std {
    template <class... Types>
    class tuple {
    public:

        [...]
        explicit tuple(const Types&...); // Marked as explicit!

        template <class... UTypes>
        explicit tuple(UTypes&&...);     // Marked as explicit!
```

For the same reason it is illegal to use copy-initialization syntax for initializing tuples:

```
std::tuple<double, double> a = {1.0, 2.0}; // ERROR!
std::tuple<double, double> a{1.0, 2.0}; // OK
```

Or to construct a tuple implicitly when passing it as an argument to a function:

```
void f(std::tuple<double, double> t) { ... }
...
f({1.0, 2.0}); // ERROR!
f(make_tuple(1.0, 2.0)); // OK
```

Accordingly, if you construct your `std::tuple` explicitly when returning it in `dummy()`, no compilation error will occur:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<double,double> dummy()
{
    return std::tuple<double, double>{2.0, 3.0}; // OK
}

int main() 
{   
    std::tuple<double,double> a = dummy();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So clang is wrong to accept this? I thought the return type could be initialized using uniform initialization (not an initializer list).

Comment: @gnzlbg: It is not a matter of compiler, rather of Standard Library implementation. Clang 3.2 does not compile this [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4hDrsS$7).

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase the question then. Is  then libc++ wrong to accept this?

Comment: @gnzlbg: Yes, this should not compile.

Comment: We should write a petition to the committee to make it non explicit for all arities > 1...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Indeed, I really don't see why this is marked as `explicit`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, that would be http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2051 (which I do not support FWIW, I'd rather have language support for calling explicit constructors in a return statement, e.g. `return auto{1,2,3}` or something else that is applicable to more than just `tuple`)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: May I ask what is the rationale for not supporting it? It works for `std::pair`, so I think it would be natural to generalize it to `std::tuple`s

Comment: I thought I just gave a rationale :)  If the desired use case is `return {a,b,c};` I would rather have a more general solution that allows list-initialization to call explicit constructors in return statements, without having to change `std::tuple`. I like having `explicit` constructors, I don't want to have to choose between them and `return {...};`, I want both.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You did suggest a generalized solution, which is indeed interesting, but applies only to returning values. Why not allowing *also* the implicit construction of tuples? I see no reason why copy-initialization should fail for `tuple`s and work for `pair`s

Comment: @JonathanWakely: while I agree that the `return` statement is `explicit` enough w.r.t the type to be selected, I still see no reason for the constructor of `std::tuple` to be `explicit` for arities > 1.

Comment: `pair` is not the paragon of good design that all things should be compared to, so I don't buy "it works for pair so it should work for tuple" as a good enough argument :) The constructor was marked explicit because you want it to be explicit for the 1-tuple case, AFAIK noone thought to make 1-tuples a special case and have a non-explicit ctor for other tuples until it was too late.

Comment: As for allowing implicit construction, I don't need it, there's no reason to prefer `tuple<...> a = { ... };` over the `tuple<...> a{...}` form. Uniform init doesn't require the `=`, and if the type isn't movable you _can't_ use the `=`, so it's better to stop using it and live in 2011+

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I'm not taking `pair` as an example of good design, I'm rather questioning why there is such a discrepancy between `pair` and a data structure which should be a generalization of `pair`. I agree the constructor should be explicit for 1-tuples.

Comment: If `pair` and `tuple` had been designed at the same time by the same people they probably would have been more consistent (and maybe `pair` would have an explicit constructor!) but they weren't, and they aren't (and it doesn't)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: On the other hand if you have a function accepting a tuple (`foo(tuple<int, double, string>)`), I would like to be able to call it this way: `foo({3, 3.0, "3"})`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that would be useful sometimes. Many of my uses of `tuple` are in variadic templates, where the arity could be zero, one or more, so even if only the 1-tuple constructor was `explicit` I'd need to be explicit, in case the template is instantiated with  `sizeof...(Args) == 1`.  I'm not strongly against LWG 2051, but I think fixing it in isolation would be unfortunate, as I'd rather see a more general solution that happens to also fix the example in LWG 2051.

Comment: Making the constructor non-explicit for arities > 1 means that variardic code will work and compile until passed a tuple of arity 0 or 1.  Having a way to say "I'm using an explicit constructor here" without having to repeat the typename doesn't have this problem...

Comment: @Yakk: Yours is an interesting argument, but I think the programmer of the variadic template would have to take this into account: they should know their function could work on tuples on any arity, thus they should construct it explicitly - or rely on the mechanism Jonathan Wakely is proposing. On the other hand, I'd still like to be able to construct a tuple implicitly for passing it as an argument. For me, the two things are not mutually exclusive: the constructor could be made explicit *and* we could have a general way of specifying that we are "using an explicit constructor"

Answer (score 24):

The answer Andy Prowl gives is correct.  I wanted to comment on the libc++ implementation, and the comment format does not allow me enough room or formatting choices.

Daniel Krügler and I had a conversation about a year ago on this subject, and he convinced me that this issue was worthy putting an extension into libc++ to get field experience with.  And so far the feedback has been positive.  However I want to make clear:  This is not as simple as removing `explicit` from the ctor `explicit constexpr tuple(UTypes&&...)`.

Daniel's plan is to give `tuple` a constructor that perfectly respects each element's implicit/explicit construction.  And **if** every element will construct implicitly from every argument in the initializer list, **then** the tuple construction is implicit, else it will be explicit.

For example:

Given:

```
#include <tuple>

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    B() = default;
    B(A);
};

struct C
{
    C() = default;
    explicit C(A);
};
```

Then:

```
std::tuple<>
test0()
{
    return {};  // ok
}
```

Nothing much to say about that one.  But also this is ok:

```
std::tuple<B>
test1B()
{
    return {A()};  // ok B(A) implicit
}
```

because the conversion from `A` to `B` is implicit.  However the following is a compile time error:

```
std::tuple<C>
test1C()
{
    return {A()};  // error, C(A) is explicit
}
```

because the conversion from `A` to `C` is explicit.  This logic continues for multi-element tuples.  For an implicit conversion to happen, every element must have an implicit conversion from the argument list:

```
std::tuple<A, B>
test2B()
{
    return {A(), A()};  // ok each element has implicit ctor
}

std::tuple<A, C>
test2C()
{
    return {A(), A()};  // error, C(A) is explicit
}
```

I should emphasize:  This is a libc++ extension at this time.

**Update**

chico made a good suggestion that I update this answer:

Since this answer was given, Daniel Krügler wrote a [paper](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3680.html) and presented it to the C++ committee in Bristol this past April.  Although the paper was well received, it was reviewed too late in the week to vote it into the current working draft.

**Update**

Daniel's proposal is now part of the [current working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf). The libc++ implementation is now set to become standard in this regard for the next C++ standard (C++17 we hope).

Comment: Is there a way to disable such extensions in libc++, in order to help keep code portable?

Comment: Not at this time.  However note that the effort to port is a compile-time error followed by a trivial fix.

Comment: Do you maintain a list of libc++ extensions? I didn't see anything in a quick look through the libc++ source and I understand you do a fair bit of experimenting. --- It's true that the once-off porting effort is trivial, but if one is doing continuous integration with build bots on half a dozen platforms it's more convenient to have your work platform flag things. Not that I'm arguing this deserves some special attention; if it were really important libc++ is open source and I could work on this myself...

Comment: No, I don't, and that's a good suggestion.  Though off the top of my head I can't think of another one besides this one.  Oh, `allocator<T>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is `true_type`.  Sometimes I just get irritated. ;-)  Though this one has already made it into the WP for the next standard: http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2103

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning the [proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3680.html) in the answer.

Comment: ```And if every element will construct implicitly from every argument in the initializer list, then the tuple construction is implicit, else it will be explicit.``` Could you explain why this is necessary? If some element cannot be constructed implicitly, it will be a compilation error, be the tuple constructor explicit or not.