# Template default argument SFINAE ambiguous to clang, fine for g++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, sfinae

I'm working on a project which involves providing an interface for users to find optima of functions of arbitrary numbers of arguments. Internally, all the mechanism is built around `std::tuple`s of the argument types. I want to provide users the ability to call my optimization routines, though, on functions written in the "usual" style (such as `f1` in the example), rather than having to write their functions to be optimized as functions of `std::tuple` instantiations (such as `f2` in the example).

As part of this mechanism, I have written an `apply` function which unpacks a tuple into the arguments of a given function and calls it.

I have also created a pair of function templates, one forwarding to the other with a lambda wrapper, providing the interface to the optimization routine. A simplified version appears below as `tuple_array_map`. The intention was to provide SFINAE for selection between the two, depending on whether the function type is callable with a tuple argument, or callable with the unpacked tuple members as arguments. I use dummy template parameters with SFINAE-triggering default arguments for this purpose.

This scheme works perfectly under g++ 4.7 and higher and compiling with `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` produces no warnings or errors.

However, when trying to compile under clang 5.1 with `-std=c++11` (sorry, I'm not a big clang user and I don't know if there's a more appropriate set of options), I get the following output for my example code:

```
clang_fail.cpp:91:5: error: call to 'tuple_array_map' is ambiguous
    tuple_array_map(f2, tuples);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang_fail.cpp:59:6: note: candidate function [with Fn = double (*)(const
      std::__1::tuple<double> &), TupleArr =
      std::__1::array<std::__1::tuple<double>, 5>, $2 = double]
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
     ^
clang_fail.cpp:69:6: note: candidate function [with Fn = double (*)(const
      std::__1::tuple<double> &), TupleArr =
      std::__1::array<std::__1::tuple<double>, 5>, $2 = double, $3 = void]
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
     ^
clang_fail.cpp:71:5: error: call to 'tuple_array_map' is ambiguous
    tuple_array_map([&](const typename TupleArr::value_type& t) {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang_fail.cpp:90:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'tuple_array_map<double (*)(double),
      std::__1::array<std::__1::tuple<double>, 5>, double, void>' requested here
    tuple_array_map(f1, tuples);
    ^
clang_fail.cpp:59:6: note: candidate function [with Fn = <lambda at
      clang_fail.cpp:71:21>, TupleArr = std::__1::array<std::__1::tuple<double>,
      5>, $2 = double]
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
     ^
clang_fail.cpp:69:6: note: candidate function [with Fn = <lambda at
      clang_fail.cpp:71:21>, TupleArr = std::__1::array<std::__1::tuple<double>,
      5>, $2 = double, $3 = void]
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
     ^
```

The really puzzling part is that it appears to deduce a `double` return from a call expression that should SFINAE out, unless I've missed something from the standard regarding either template default arguments or SFINAE itself.

Example follows---it's as minimal as I could get it while still triggering the same behavior:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

double f1(double x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

double f2(const std::tuple<double>& x)
{
    return std::get<0>(x) * 2;
}

template<std::size_t N>
struct apply_impl {
    template<class F, class Tuple, class... TParams>
    static auto apply(F&& fn, Tuple&& t, TParams&&... args)
      ->  decltype(
              apply_impl<N - 1>::apply(
                  std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
                  std::get<N - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)),
                  std::forward<TParams>(args)...
          ))
    {
        return apply_impl<N - 1>::apply(
                std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
                std::get<N - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)),
                std::forward<TParams>(args)...
                );
    }
};

template<>
struct apply_impl<0> {
    template<class F, class Tuple, class... TParams>
    static auto apply(F&& fn, Tuple&&, TParams&&... args)
      -> decltype(std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<TParams>(args)...))
    {
        return std::forward<F>(fn)(std::forward<TParams>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class F, class Tuple>
auto apply(F&& fn, Tuple&& t)
  -> decltype(apply_impl<
          std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value
        >::apply(std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(t)))
{
    return apply_impl<
        std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value
      >::apply(std::forward<F>(fn), std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<class Fn, class TupleArr,
    class = decltype(std::declval<Fn>()(
                std::declval<typename TupleArr::value_type>()))>
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        static_cast<void>(f(arr[i]));
}

template<class Fn, class TupleArr,
    class = decltype(apply(std::declval<Fn>(),
                std::declval<typename TupleArr::value_type>())),
    class = void>
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr)
{
    tuple_array_map([&](const typename TupleArr::value_type& t) {
                return apply(f, t);
            }, arr);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::tuple<double>, 5> tuples = {
        std::make_tuple(1),
        std::make_tuple(2),
        std::make_tuple(3),
        std::make_tuple(4),
        std::make_tuple(5)
    };

    // "apply" unpacks a tuple into arguments to a function
    apply(f1, tuples[0]);

    // this call produces an ambiguity one level down under clang
    tuple_array_map(f1, tuples);
    // this call directly produces an ambiguity under clang
    tuple_array_map(f2, tuples);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the bug seems to be in `libc++`; compiling with `clang++-3.5` and gcc-4.8's `libstdc++` gives me no errors.

Comment: I would go further and risk that the problem is in the implementation of `std::array` by `libc++`...

Comment: Related: [Returning a tuple from a function using uniform initialization syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961809/returning-a-tuple-from-a-function-using-uniform-initialization-syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ambiguity when compiling with libc++ is due to the lack of the standard-mandated `explicit` specifier on `std::tuple`'s converting constructor ([Constructor #2 at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)). Consequently, `double` is implicitly convertible to `std::tuple<double>` ([See this example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f500a9fc30b0d5d)) so *both* of your `tuple_apply_map` functions are viable.

As a workaround, I suggest creating a `needs_apply` trait and using that to constrain your `tuple_apply_map` templates (I'll use tag dispatching):

```
template<class Fn, class TupleArr>
struct needs_apply {
    template <class F=Fn>
    static auto test(int) ->
      decltype(std::declval<F>()(*std::declval<TupleArr>().begin()), std::false_type{});
    static auto test(...) -> std::true_type;
    using type = decltype(test(0));
};

template<class Fn, class TupleArr>
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr, std::false_type)
{
    for (auto&& i : arr)
        static_cast<void>(f(i));
}

template<class Fn, class TupleArr>
void tuple_array_map(Fn f, const TupleArr& arr, std::true_type)
{
    tuple_array_map([&](const typename TupleArr::value_type& t) {
                return apply(f, t);
            }, arr, std::false_type{});
}

template<class Fn, class TupleArr>
void tuple_array_map(Fn&& f, TupleArr&& arr) {
    tuple_array_map(std::forward<Fn>(f), std::forward<TupleArr>(arr),
                    typename needs_apply<Fn,TupleArr>::type{});
}
```

This works correctly [with libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c07a3ab6326cd80a) and [with libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5fddc86677fc7dc) and even [compiling with g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1b0614590c675ad).

[According to this answer by Howard Hinnant, this non-conformance of the `std::tuple` constructor is an extension implemented in libc++ as an experiment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14963014/923854) 
See also [Library Working Group active issue 2051](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2051) and [the paper N3680 written by Daniel Krügler to address the issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3680.html).

Comment: Ahh! I'd wondered about that but I'd only written the "other way round" counter example. Good catch, thanks.